# Tkinter - Making Program Wait for User Input

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that calculates a persons BMI after the user gives his height and weight.

I used `variable.insert()` to insert a value so the program doesn't have errors.

Is there any way to have the program start 'empty' without getting errors? Basically, I need it to not do anything until the calculate button is pressed.

```
from Tkinter import *

class App(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)

    self.height()
    self.weigh()
    self.output()
    self.calculate()


  def height(self):

    Label(self, text = "Enter Height, feet").grid()

    self.feet = Entry(self)
    self.feet.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    self.feet.insert(0, "1")



    Label(self, text = "Enter Height, inches").grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    self.inches = Entry(self)
    self.inches.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    self.inches.insert(0, "1")


  def weigh(self):

    Label(self, text = "Enter Weight").grid(row =2, column = 0)

    self.weight = Entry(self)
    self.weight.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    self.weight.insert(0, "1")


  def output(self):
    self.calcBMI = Button(self, text = "Calculate BMI")
    self.calcBMI.grid(row = 6, columnspan = 2)
    self.calcBMI["command"] = self.calculate


    Label(self, text = "Body Mass Index").grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.lblbmi = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
    self.lblbmi.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = "we")



    Label(self, text = "Status").grid(row = 5, column = 0)
    self.lblstat = Label(self, bg = "#fff", anchor = "w", relief = "groove")
    self.lblstat.grid(row = 5, column = 1, sticky = "we")



  def calculate(self):

    ft = int(self.feet.get())
    inch = int(self.inches.get())
    ht = ft * 12 + inch
    wt = int(self.weight.get())

    bmi = (wt * 703) / (ht ** 2)

    self.lblbmi["text"] = "%.2f" % bmi

    if bmi > 30:
        self.lblstat["text"] = "Obese"
    elif bmi > 25:
        self.lblstat["text"] = "Overweight"
    elif bmi > 18.5:
        self.lblstat["text"] = "Normal"
    else:
        self.lblstat["text"] = "Underweight"



def main():
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Why are you calling calculate() in the init?  If you don't do this and disable the Calculate button until the fields are populated, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing right now is calling the output outright(& also by pressing the calculate button). What you need to do is call it only when the button is pressed

From `init()` remove `self.calculate()`.

Now just remove all the `insert` statements. You don't need them anymore ;)

## Edit:

As Joe suggested in his comment, you could also *disable* the button until all the fields are populated. You could do this by setting its `state` to `disabled`,like this:

```
self.calcBMI.config(state='disabled')
```

Comment: The first method worked and is exactly what I needed for the assignment, but just for reference, will that line alone make sure the program will only run if all fields are populated?

Comment: No that's just to disable the button. To make sure all the fields are populated,you have to `get()` (like you did to calculate the BMI) the fields & make sure they are not empty

Comment: If you find my answer informative & helpful,kindly [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. Its a way of telling people that you have found the answer. No obligations,however :)